# AWS Spectrum Scan Error Unexpected end of compressed file

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, amazon-redshift-spectrum

I want to use AWS Spectrum - Querying on Redshift based on a file in S3.

Since you can either choose a folder in S3 or a JSON file, I opted to use a JSON file as the location.

The bug:

When I reference the file `test` in a folder - Redshift works perefectly.

When I reference the `JSON file` which references the file `test` and I try to do a query that runs on the whole file, it fails:

```
select count(*)
from test
```

The error: `Unexpected end of compressed file. File may be truncated.`

The weird thing is - if I only query X amount of rows, it works:

```
select *
from test
limit 100;
```

This means that the columns of the table I created (when I created the external table) are correct. Am I missing something in the JSON file? Here is how I wrote it (taken from AWS Docs):

```
{
  "entries": [
    {"url":"s3://s3_bucket/SpectrumTest/test.gz", "meta": { "content_length": 4668469 } }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`content_length` is the size of the file in `bytes`. Because the file changed but JSON manifest remained with the old content_length, it didn't load the whole file resulting in the error about the end of the compressed file.

The reason doing `limit 100` worked is because DBeaver saved the results in cache.

Hope this helps anyone else in the future.